# Date Picker for WP eCommerce Checkout Page

Tags: wordpress, e-commerce

I'm using the WP eCommerce plugin for WordPress and was wondering if there is anyway to put a datepicker on the checkout page. For those familiar with the plugin, I'd need to the picked dates to appear in the Sales Log. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can check this plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/order-delivery-date/ :Ashok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just released Version 2.0 of this plugin for WP e-Commerce. It allows to capture Delivery Date & Time both. It is supported by loads of settings & features that help in same-day/next-day delivery, holidays, 24 different themes, etc.

Version 2.0: http://www.tychesoftwares.com/store/premium-plugins/order-delivery-date-for-wp-e-commerce-woocommerce-pro